# Assignment and Copy Behaviour for Arrays In Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

If I create arrays from another array like :

```
var ArrayOne = [1,2,3,4]
var ArrayTwo = ArrayOne
var ArrayThree = ArrayTwo
```

Now According to array's assignment and copy behaviour if I change any value from ArrayTwo it will reflected in ArrayOne and ArrayThree. but If I append/remove in arrayTwo it will not reflect in ArrayOne/ArrayThree because array's instance changes.

```
ArrayTwo[0] = 100
println(ArrayTwo[0])
// 100
println(ArrayThree[0])
// 100
```

and

```
ArrayTwo.append(5)
ArrayTwo[0] = 999
println(ArrayTwo[0])
// 999
println(ArrayThree[0])
// 100
```

Is there any way to modified all array simultaneously without creating new copy/instance of array on every modification(append/remove).

Comment: Just use extra indirection.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays, Dictionaries and Strings are all structs and passed by value in Swift. To get this behavior you could try using NSArray or creating your own Swift class.